# Interbase Entity Framework Core 7.13.1 SQL error

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

What is this error?

> Exception thrown: 'InterBaseSql.Data.InterBaseClient.IBException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> Dynamic SQL Error
> SQL error code = -104
> Token unknown - line 3, column 29

I upgraded to 7.13.1 and then got this error